# OAauth2 - Set Permission Based On Scopes, Claims Or Both?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, openid

I'm not sure if the permission validation in the resource server routes should be on the claims or the scope of the access token. For example:
a scope can be set to 'can-view-pictures' but a claim can be 'role: admin'. So In my resource server should I base the check on the scopes of the claims or a combination of both? Is there a rule of thumb? 
Best,
Tal

Answer (score 0):

I would use scopes as high level privileges - can I call tbis service? Because scopes have to be configured in the Authorization Server, which is very central. Meanwhile claims are very product specific. Hope this post helps you to understand the separation: https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/